# I have to write a program in which after typing three names it should answer me with "Hello <firstName>!"

Tags: c#, console.writeline

I have to write a program in which after typing three names it should answer me with "Hello  !", but there is problems with the Console.Writeline function...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace homework1
{
    class Program
    { 
        static int Main()
        {
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            string surName = Console.ReadLine();
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + firstName[] + "!");

            //Console.WriteLine("Your full name is " + fullName + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason use `firstName[]` instead of `firstName`?

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace homework1
{
    class Program
    { 
        static int Main()
        {
            string firstName = Console.ReadLine();
            string surName = Console.ReadLine();
            string lastName = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + firstName + "!");

            Console.WriteLine("Your full name is " + 
                String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", firstName, surName , lastName ) + ".");

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a working example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, " + firstName + "!");
```